# HDMI sound keeps dropping out after last update - macOS 10.13.5

Tags: display, audio, software-update, displayport

I have an external monitor connected to the MacBook Pro 2017 with touchbar, and everything was working fine until the last update, now every day I have to reboot the computer to get back the sound through the display port or HDMI.

It doesn't show the Monitor when pressing on the speaker icon anymore, I tried killing all audio processes, `coreaudiod`, etc, logging out, sleeping, etc, the only solution is to reboot.

```
  System Version:   macOS 10.13.5 (17F77)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 17.6.0
```